# MongoDB execute query from a file and measure time

Tags: mongodb

I have a txt file with mongoDB queries, like this:

```
db.telephone.find({'brand' : 'Apple'});
db.telephone.find({'brand' : 'Samsung'});
```

...to a total of about 1500 rows. I am executing this query like this.

```
mongo myDatabase C:\path\mongoDB.txt
```

Now I need to measure the time how long it takes to execute all of these queries. I dont really care about the output, I really only care about the time it takes (as a part of an experiment).

I thought that if I create a collection `times` and insert current time to it like this `db.times.insert({time: Date()});` at the **beginning and end of the query file**, it would do what I need, but it seemingly does not work, as both of these result times are the same in the end (and I believe that executing all these queries did take more than 1 second for sure).

Is this because I dont print the output, so the queries dont really get executed? Or why does this not work? And is there a better way how to measure the time it takes to execute these queries **from a file?** Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign start and end time in the file itself. The following is an example:

```
var start_time = new Date().valueOf();
db.telephone.find({'brand' : 'Apple'});
db.telephone.find({'brand' : 'Samsung'});
var end_time = new Date().valueOf();
print(end_time-start_time);
```

**How we can precisely measure the execution time?**

To analyze the query, we can use [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/). It returns the complete statistics of the query. The following is an example:

```
db.telephone.find({'brand' : 'Apple'}).explain("executionStats")
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "check.telephone",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "brand" : {
                "$eq" : "Apple"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "brand" : {
                    "$eq" : "Apple"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 35,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "brand" : {
                    "$eq" : "Apple"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 3,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 1
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "theMechanic",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.0.11",
        "gitVersion" : "417d1a712e9f040d54beca8e4943edce218e9a8c"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Note:** The `executionStats.executionTimeMillis` holds actual query execution time.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this solution and the printed result was 21. I suppose it is in milliseconds. Can that be real? For 1500 queries on a DB that has 1 000 000 rows? Sounds like there is something wrong to me.

Comment: @P.Paul Two things to consider here. I. If the queries are similar to what to you specified and there is proper indexing on fields, this time is feasible. II. The find() only returns the iterator and not the actual data. Updating my answer with more insights on how we can precisely measure the execution time.

Comment: @mr-s-sharma I tried to use your suggested method `.explain("executionStats")` on the first query I have in my file, and it gave me 391 ms in `executionStats.executionTimeMillis` for just this one query. So the total time of 21 ms must be wrong. I still dont see why tho...

Comment: @P.Paul You can consider ```executionStats.executionTimeMillis``` a source of truth

Comment: Ok, but does this mean that there is no way how to achieve my original goal, that is measuring the time of all these queries in a file together?